# PHP, javascript, ajax - communication between 2 users

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, communication

Good day to all.

I need to do this:

When user X press a button user Y sees a photo. Before that user Y sees nothing.

I did this like this: I created a database on a mysql server and created a table with photos and flags. When user X presses the button I send an ajax request and change the flag to the corresponding photo. User Y also sends ajax request every 1 sec to see if anything has changed.

Sounds ok, looks ok, works... it does but to so ok. When 100000 users send 1 ajax request every 1 second the server crashes. First mysql server then apache.

So... my question is is there anyway to do this without so many ajax requests? Something like send the page with a certain "thing" that tells the browser to keep the same socket and send later the image? Something like a stream but instead of images to be html pages/images/whatever.

I know java applet would be a solution but I would need a php(for server side)+js(for client side) solution.

And yes I know that I'll probably get an "you can't" answer but it deserves a try.

Comment: Does it have to be every 1 second? What about 3 seconds? That immediately reduces the load to 1/3 - if it would crash at 100,000 users, you could then use ( theoretically ) 300,000 users.

Comment: Actually I kind of need to make the requests at 0.5... 1 was a compromise. Also I added a clean up time... for 10 seconds at every 120 seconds users don't send anything... still is not ok.

Comment: Do you have a possibility for HTTPS? I'm asking this because you then have a secure tunnel with every client computer, thus being able to send asynchronous responses back to the client.

Comment: I have... actually I have possibility to use any protocol... How do I send the responses?

Comment: I have found something that might be very interesting for your needs, I will post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because HTTP is stateless, you need to create a permanent or long-lasting socket connection between clients and server.

This is a chat application, written in PHP, AJAX and Ruby backend.

[Web Chat application main page](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ajax-chat/index.php?title=Main_Page), more specifically the [part about the socket server](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ajax-chat/index.php?title=Socket_Server)

Answer (score 2):

What about [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets)?

edit.
[HTTP keep-alive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) might help.

Comment: Well... something like that. But on what I read there they are implemented only in newer browsers... and I also don't see IE... I doubt my boss will agree with that. (Even though I would)